# php cli windows ftp_connect fails getaddrinfo failed: no such host is known

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

i have a windows 7 machine
i use php 5.4 CLI

when i try to use ftp_connect:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("10.192.35.100‎");
```

the the following error raise and connection fails:

```
getaddrinfo failed: no such host is known
```

when i try to use `FTP` from `CMD`  i can reach the ftp server (which is in the inner network)

it seems like DNS problem but i don't use a domain name but ip address. 
i tried using the machine external ip address but got the same problem.

any idea about this wierd problem?

Comment: Have you given the `$username` and `$password` /

Comment: ftp_connect don't accept user and password - it's only creating the stream

Comment: I guess you missed to show some details. I guessif you just use the following code (and nothing more) it will not throw that error. `<?php ftp_connect("10.192.35.100");`

Comment: hek2mgl - tried what you suggested - this is what i get
PHP Warning:  ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in C:\phpdev\ftp-con.php on line 4